# Obtaining Azure AD token with Grant_Type=password in fiddler

Tags: oauth-2.0, fiddler, azure-active-directory, access-token

I was wondering if it is possible to obtain azure ad token in fiddler for a specific user with grant_type=password in fiddler.

I've followed [THIS](https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-grant-in-AzureAd) wiki in Github, but I can't get it to work.

I get this error message:

> AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the f2f535e0-294f-4704-befc-8ce754f10bd7 directory.

And i know i have added the account because that's the global admin account which is owner over the AD.

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong.

This is what i'm doing:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/f2f535e0-294f-4704-befc-8ce754f10bd7/oauth2/token

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Host: login.microsoftonline.com

grant_type=password&resource=<my application app id>&client_id=<my application client id>&username=<my account>&password=<mypassword>
```

Comment: f2f535e0-294f-4704-befc-8ce754f10bd7 are you sure this is the right objectId?

Comment: Yes i strongly believe so, because i tried with a grant_type=client_credentials  against the same object-id in the URL and i got status-code 200 ok and a token back. What i want to do is to get the token through username and password.

Comment: Error message implies the user account is not in the tenant you are trying to sign into. I would do some sanity checks, because what you are trying to do should work in general.

Comment: It's likely your tenant id is incorrect or the app is registered in a different tenant.  You can try just using login.mso/common to bypass the need for the tenant id.

Comment: Ok, so i found the solution. I had to include the client_secret parameter into the grant_type. It didn't specify it in the guide so i for some reason assumed i didn't have to. But after i did it worked.. good to know.
anyways, Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

ROPC is not supported in hybrid identity federation scenarios (for example, Azure AD and ADFS used to authenticate on-premises accounts, this means you have only sync the users in the azure ad from on prem ad but not syncronize the password). If users are full-page redirected to an on-premises identity providers, Azure AD is not able to test the username and password against that identity provider.